# Replace a file from .war with another file using Cron Job

Tags: java, tomcat, cron

I have a **mayapp.war** which is deployed in `tomcat` server. I want to replace a file(test.properties) which resides inside **myapp.war** with another file(test.properties) and this file resides outside **myapp.war**. I want to do this stuff using a **cron job**. will appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

A war file is just a zip file. You can use any zip command tool to replace a file or you can use the jar command from the JDK.

Use following command:

```
jar uf myapp.war test.properties
```